# Can you block a specific site from automatically downloading a file?

Tags: google-chrome

When I have a video conference with Zoom or WebEx, I prefer to use the web version of the client. However, the meeting links always directs me to a page that auto downloads the desktop client. Is there a way to prevent a site from automatically downloading a file like this? There is a setting in Chrome to disable automatic downloads, but it is only to prevent sites from downloading multiple files automatically.

Comment: If you can't find an answer for Chrome, Safari can do this, per site, in prefs/websites/downloads… Allow/Deny/Ask as global or site-specific settings

Comment: the zoom invites usually include two links, the one which redirects to the client and the web version....

Comment: Most browsers can be set to ask if a download should begin. And yes, many Zoom users *only* send the link, which causes that annoyance.

Comment: This might be the only way to achieve what I want.